# ScrollView not show content React-native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I'm building an application using react-native was all right until I needed to add ScrollView, no matter what screen I add and the content stops being rendered, no error is displayed, whatever is occurring is silent, I've tried Several things I saw on the internet but nothing solved my problem, I put an example code below...

My code:

```
export default () => (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>

             // My page content here

        </ScrollView>    
    </View>
);
```

Apparently it's something simple but I did not find the solution, if anyone can help me thank you.

Comment: is it rendering anything without scrollview? I mean if you put something else otherthan scrollview inside outer view component, does it render that or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a height and width to the scroll view's style, and then work your way from there.

Or

make it absolute position and set the top, left, bottom and right position to 0 as such

```
position: 'absolute',
top: 0,
left: 0,
right: 0,
bottom: 0
```

Answer (score 15):

The code that fixed this for me was to use `contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}` rather than just style. This sets the flex on the outer container of the scrollview, rather than the inner container.

Comment: This drove me crazy contentContainerStyle is so key!

Comment: after adding this is the scroll view is not scrolling

Answer (score 3):

I think because you used flex style in root and in scrollview. That's effect to your display data not fit in screen. Try to remove `flex` all of them and run it without `flex` style first.

Answer (score 2):

if you can add some space to end of scrollview , you will probably be able to see all content

```
 export default () => (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{flex: 1,paddingBottom: 300}}>
             // Page content here
        </View>    
      </ScrollView>
    );
```

Comment: Man, that's amaising and easy solution! Helps me a lot. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

This should fix problem:

```js
export default () => (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView }>
         // Page content 
    </ScrollView >    
  </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'flex: 1' is causing the issue, because ScrollView is used whenever the content overflows, so obviously you shouldn't be specifying it's width. Try this instead-

```
export default () => (
  <ScrollView>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
         // Page content here
    </View>    
  </ScrollView>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The ScrollView component inherit the View height.
You can try this

```
<View style={{flex: 1, height: 100}}>
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
         // My page content here
    </ScrollView>    
</View>
```

It's late, but maybe it's still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my problem was that I was using percentage on `height` for each `View`, it seems that `scrollview` doesn't works in that way

For example: `height :30%` won't work
`height 300` will do

Answer (score 0):

The ScrollView gets it's height (Flex) from the view that wrapps it , you might want to wrap it between (<> </>)

Answer (score 0):

Gonna thow my 2 pents in here.

I had this issue with a ScollList that was part of a child component.

The child component was being consumed by a parent component.

The parent component was imported and displayed in a Screen.

Screen top View styles: must include flex:1

Parent Component top View style: must include flex:1

Child component that contains ScrollList: requires only cosmetic styles no flex.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).